# TimeoutError: waiting for selector '--selector--' failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping, timeout, puppeteer

If I run code without 'waitForSelector' it gives 'null' and when I run it with 'waitForSelector' it gives time exceeded error. I already have tried giving custom value for timeout but still the problem persist.

error: Timeout or other error:  TimeoutError: waiting for selector `[class*="header-content"] span:nth-child(2)` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded

Output needed: '1 views'

**Code:**

```
const viewsData = async () => {   
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()   
  const page = await browser.newPage()    
  await page.goto("https://www.loom.com/share/5b920dc1375f43fa9b622ac0a6ba7c52")   
  await page    
    .waitForSelector(`[class*="header-content"] span:nth-child(2)`)   
    .then(() => {  
      console.log("Success")   
    })   
    .catch((err) => {    
      console.log("Timeout or other error: ", err)   
    })    
  let re = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector(`[class*="header-content"] span:nth-child(2)`))   
  console.log(re)    
  await browser.close()   
}    
viewsData()
```

Comment: first you could check what you get in HTML because it seems you never get this element.

Comment: I do, on broweser with this query i do get '1 views' but in console as i stated, get null(without waitFor) and error: time exceeded with (waitFor)

Comment: don't check in `broweser` but in code - code may get different HTML than real browser. Some servers may send different content to different browsers and devices (phone, netobook, desktop). Servers may also send Captcha to block scripts/bots/spamers/hackers - and maybe in HTML you have captcha/message which could explain problem.

Comment: got where the issue is, we have to be signed in to see how many views the video has, and when puppeteer runs we are not signed in. so it gives 'null'.

Answer (score -1):

```
 await page    
    .waitForSelector(`[class*="header-content"] span:nth-child(2)`, {timeout:0})   
    .then(() => {  
      console.log("Success")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: timeout: 0 is dangerous, hanging your script and stifing the error. This ignores the deeper problem.